# Rails 3: guides.rubyonrails.org in PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Where to find Rails 3 guides in PDF to read offline?

Thanks

Comment: I'm keeping a HTML version here: https://github.com/viniciuspinto/rails-guides

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't get them in PDF, but you can get them in HTML form by running these commands:

```
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
cd rails
git checkout origin/3-2-stable -b 3-2-stable
cd railties/guides
ruby rails_guides.rb
cd output
open index.html
```

When these commands have finished you should be in the `railties/guides/output` folder which contains the HTML versions of the guides that were just generated with `ruby rails_guides.rb`, and if you're on a decent operating system then you'll see the homepage in your default browser.

Comment: Don't know about windows but in OSX from the print menu you can save as pdf.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Bigg, Ruby-guides document is really too useful. Your solution help me to get it.

Comment: You may need to '$ gem install RedCloth' if you don't have the RedCloth gem already.

Comment: Checkout the `3-2-stable` branch for the most recent version of the guides, as of the time of this comment

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? Doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: Zenph: Yes, it does actually. Did you read the first line?

Answer (score 12):

Here is its official release of mobi format:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/kindle/ruby_on_rails_guides_v4.2.5.mobi

found at the sidebar on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Looks like the first link is now broken (it's [3.2.6](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/kindle/ruby_on_rails_guides_v3.2.6.mobi) now), but the link on the sidebar seems to be up to date.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: Fixed the link (it's 4.2.5 now.)
The official website no longer provides Rails 3

Answer (score 8):

I'm using rails 4 rc1, so the instructions provided by @ryan-bigg in the accepted answer where not working. I found the solution in the [Ruby on Rails Guides Guideline](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/ruby_on_rails_guides_guidelines.html#html-guides-generation):

```
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
cd rails/guides
bundle install
bundle exec rake guides:generate:html
```

and now I have the HTML guides in the rails/guides/output folder.

Answer (score 6):

I found them at http://ruby.kyoto-wu.ac.jp/RailsDocs/ (Ruby on Rails Guides (v4.2.0) as pdf or html)

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer: As of writing this, 4.0.2 is the most stable version.

```
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
cd rails
bundle install
bundle exec rake guides:generate
```

Open rails/guides/output/index.html .

Answer (score 1):

[Download RAR file from here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71971410/Rails%20Guides.rar)

Enjoy Rails. Thanks.

Comment: thank for sharing, but the pdf files are for rails 2.3 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, you can download the entire contents of guides.rubyonrails.org with this simple single-line command:

```sh
wget -r -k -p -L guides.rubyonrails.org/
```

This will create a new folder `guides.rubyonrails.org` in your current working directory and then save each page of the site locally. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score -6):

http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails you need to buy this book.

or http://api.rubyonrails.org/ complete API guide.

or search google with this query "ruby rails tutorial + pdf" you will get lot of content most of them are in pdf form.