# Rails Guides offline documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation

Is there an downloadable offline version of the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506019/rails-3-guides-rubyonrails-org-in-pdf

Comment: Can someone of the "clothers" explain why this question should be off topic? Documentation is important for programming!

Comment: I agree.  I came here to find out how to generate or download offline docs for Rails, which I believe to be a legitimate question about "software tools commonly used by programmers".  I would like to see this question reopened so that the answer can be improved.

Comment: I'm keeping a HTML version here: https://github.com/viniciuspinto/rails-guides.git

Comment: Didn't get the reason why this question is closed!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comment of 'Shreyas Satish' led me to the rails guides on my harddisk. I had only to build it.

After installing Ruby (1.8) on Ubuntu:

```
sudo gem install rails
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev # required for RedCloth
sudo gem install RedCloth
sudo ruby /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/guides/rails_guides.rb
```

then browse to:

```
file:///var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/guides/output/index.html
```

Comment: At least for Rails 3.2 (but I also suspect for older versions), you can do "rake doc:guides" to render the guides into HTML and place them in the doc/guides/ subdirectory of the app.  Note that you will need to add RedCloth to your Gemfile to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Might be, this is the one you're looking for: http://railsapi.com/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but very nice! Thanks.